# What is the symbol for the Spacebar Key when creating custom Key-Bindings in OS 10.7?

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion, key-bindings

**I would like to create custom key-bindings in `OS 10.7 Lion` that do the following:**

1. **`option` + `space` = `right arrow`**
2. **`control` + `space` = `left arrow`**

I have read [this article](http://blog.macromates.com/2005/key-bindings-for-switchers/) in the Textmate Blog outlining how to create custom key-bindings by first creating the following file: `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict`, and inside the file, entering the key `character code` and the `Cocoa action` that you would like to perform.

The problem is, I can't seem to locate the `character code` for the `spacebar` anywhere! And are there actions to mimic the `right arrow` and `left arrow`?

Lastly, if there is an easier method of doing this that I'm overlooking, please let me know. I really only care about this binding within Textmate, although having it throughout Lion would be nice.

Thanks.

Comment: The character code for space is 0x20

Answer (score 0):

No symbol needed. You just use a space.

So, for example:

```
{
    /* Modifier keys: start with C-m */
    "^m" = {
        " " = ("insertText:", "Hello world");
    }
}
```

With this key-bindings dictionary, if you press ctrl-m and then space, it'll insert “Hello world”.